# Why the boilerplates when writing new Monad Transformers

Tags: monads, boilerplate, monad-transformers, haskell

This section http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html#id659032 from the book Real World Haskell suggests that when writing a new Monad Transformer, we have to derive instances for `MonadState`, `MonadIO`, etc. manually.

But I tried the following and it compiled. Why is it not done in the library?

Say I have the `MaybeT` monad transformers:

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT {
    runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a)
}

instance Monad m => Monad (MaybeT m) where -- blah blah

instance MonadTrans MaybeT where
    lift = MaybeT . (liftM Just)
```

Then once we know that `t` is a `MonadTrans` and `m` is a `Monad`, why can't everything else be automatically derived like this?

```
instance (MonadTrans t, Monad (t m), MonadIO m) => MonadIO (t m) where
    liftIO = lift . liftIO

instance (MonadTrans t, Monad (t m), MonadState s m) => MonadState s (t m) where
    get = lift get
    put = lift . put
```

Does the author mean we have to do this manually for each new `MonadTrans` or I get him wrong?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: The GHC extension GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving can automatically create the instances for some of the monad classes, though I've never found a list of which ones. Completely parametric instances like your MonadIO and MonadState above are "bad form". As FUZxxl says below, there may be different use cases for specializations, but also, if you have a class method that is "obviously parametric" but you only have one obvious instance it should just be a plain parametric function rather than a class method.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. But I'm a little slow here. What part of my code does your last sentence refer to? ('obviously parametric' class method but only one obvious instance). Can you explain further?

Comment: Hi Po. The last sentence is a general observation, not related to your code. But by reversing the logic as put and get are class methods in the "standard library" we can reasonably expect them to make sense as methods not over-generalized functions - so the upshot (or downshot) is you have to write type specific cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why they don't do this is very simple:

1. First, it would break a lot of old code if they would add this, because you need some stuff like `UndecidableInstances` to let GHC decide between the automatic and the manually defined instance.  This would be very cumbersome.
2. What, if you want to define an instance different from the above, maybe for performance reasons or to do some hack? I think this little boilerplate is preferable over the inability / higher cost (because of the trickery to tell GHC which instance you want) of defining customized instances, if this instance would be builtin.